# How to send entire data of specific row of table to server- Android

Tags: android, json, android-tablelayout

I am creating online shopping application for android and i have created a table which displays data from the server regarding the availability of the item. I have added a button next to it which adds that item of that row to the cart and it should send data to the server as well regarding which item was selected.

My problem is that i am not able to figure out how to send entire data of the specific row to the server and it should not re-direct from the current screen. Also my server is in php and is ready.

```
public class Availability extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_availability);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        final GetDatafromDB_Availability getdb = new GetDatafromDB_Availability();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users_availability> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users_availability> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users_availability> users = new ArrayList<Users_availability>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users_availability user = new Users_availability();
                user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
                user.setProduct_code(json_data.getString("product_code"));
                user.setShapes(json_data.getString("shaps"));
                user.setPair(json_data.getString("pair"));
                user.setCarats(json_data.getString("carats"));
                user.setColor(json_data.getString("color"));
                user.setClarity(json_data.getString("clarity"));
                user.setService(json_data.getString("service"));
                user.setPolish(json_data.getString("polish"));
                user.setSymetric(json_data.getString("symetric"));
                user.setTables(json_data.getString("tables"));
                user.setMeasurements(json_data.getString("measurments"));
                user.setFlourscne(json_data.getString("flourscne"));
                user.setDescription(json_data.getString("description"));
                user.setCerticated(json_data.getString("certificated"));
                user.setCcode(json_data.getString("ccode"));
                user.setCut(json_data.getString("cut"));
                user.setTotal(json_data.getString("total"));
                user.setFile(json_data.getString("file"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }



    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("Product code");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView shapes = new TextView(this);
        shapes.setText("Shapes");
        shapes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        shapes.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        shapes.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(shapes,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView pair = new TextView(this);
        pair.setText("Shapes");
        pair.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pair.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pair.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pair,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.





        TextView flourscne = new TextView(this);
        flourscne.setText("flourscne");
        flourscne.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        flourscne.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        flourscne.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(flourscne,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView description = new TextView(this);
        description.setText("description");
        description.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        description.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        description.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(description,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView certificated = new TextView(this);
        certificated.setText("certificated");
        certificated.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        certificated.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        certificated.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(certificated,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView ccode = new TextView(this);
        ccode.setText("ccode");
        ccode.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ccode.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        ccode.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(ccode,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView cut = new TextView(this);
        cut.setText("cut");
        cut.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        cut.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cut.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(cut,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView total = new TextView(this);
        total.setText("total");
        total.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        total.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        total.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(total,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView file = new TextView(this);
        file.setText("file");
        file.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        file.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        file.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(file,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users_availability> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users_availability p = (Users_availability) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getproduct_code());
            label.setId(p.getId());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView place = new TextView(this);
            place.setText(p.getShapes());
            place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            place.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(place,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.



            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getCut());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getTotal());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getFile());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Add to Basket");
            // btn.setTextSize();
            btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
            // btn.setTag(mLinks.get(index));
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            params.width=400;
            params.height=60;
            // btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
            Ll.addView(btn,params);

            tr.addView((View)Ll);


            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //  startActivity(f1);

    }
}
```

this is the class which contains the JSON parsing code

```
public class GetDatafromDB_Availability {


    public String getDataFromDB()  {

        HttpPost httppost;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/availability.php"); 
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            return "error";
        }

        return response.trim();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AsyncTask` for heavy-duty loadings such as http requests or parsing. Don't run such tasks on the ui thread, they will freeze it.

In the `AsyncTask` implementation's `onPostExecute` method you have the response you can deal with, populate your gui elements, update the views, etc.

A few references that may help you on how to proceed:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U3Rd98cRamE